# Equivalence class in X as a subset of $\mathscr P(X)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

Due to Halmos:

> There is no standard notation for the equivalence class of $x$ with
>   respect to $R$; we shall usually denote it by $x/R$, and we shall
>   write $X/R$ for the set of all equivalence classes $\ldots$
>
> Exercise: show that $X/R$ is indeed a set by exhibiting a condition
>   that specifies exactly the subset $X/R$ of the power set $\mathscr
> P(X)$.
>
> ~P. R. Halmos, *Naive Set Theory* (p. 28)

**EDIT:** Taking the answers I've received thus far, here's what I'm currently working with.

Let $X$ be a set, and let $R$ be an equivalence relation in $X$. Then $x/R$ (or $[x]$ if you prefer) is a set comprising the elements $y$ such that $(x, y) \in R$. Each such equivalence class for each element $x \in X$ is a subset of $X$ and therefore a member of $\mathscr P(X)$.

This in turn means that $X/R$, the set of all $x/R$ for our given $X$ and our given equivalence $R$, is a set of subsets of $X$, making it a subset of $\mathscr P(X)$. Now, I've worked through two examples:

If we let $X = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and let $R$ be the relation of equality in $X$, then $X/R = \{\{1\}, \{2\}, \{3\}, \{4\}\}$. This is a subset of $\mathscr P(X)$ as expected.

If we let $X = \{1, 2, 3\}$ and let $R$ be the cartesian product $X \times X$, then $X/R = \{\{1, 2, 3\}\}$, which is a subset of $\mathscr P(X)$ as expected.

As for how one can come up with a general specification that achieves both of these results:

$$X/R = \{S \in \mathscr P(X): (s \in S) \iff ([t \in S] \land [s \space R \space t]) \}$$

Or, in English, the set of equivalence classes in $X$ with respect to a given relation $R$ is the set of all sets $S$ in the power set of $X$ for which an element $s$ is only in $S$ if there is also $t$ in $S$ and $s$ and $t$ stand in equivalence to one another.

This strikes me as a massive cop out, but I'm stuck on how to take it more primitive.

Comment: Nope, not yet. Notice that $S$ and $T$ are subsets of $X$, so $(S,T)\in R$ doesn't make sense. But you are improving, don't give up. A hint: as you have said, each equivalence class is an element of $P(X)$, say $S$. Which properties does $S$ have?? Which special property?

Comment: Well, I am noticing that the sets $S$ formed in this way would all be disjoint with each other. For the time being that's the only thing I'm noticing, but I will think on it further.

Comment: Yes. That's the first property they have. Well done. But there is also another one.

Comment: At least in any of the examples I've considered, it would appear that the unions of all the equivalence classes would be equal to the original set? So it's the subset of P(X) which is simultaneously disjoint and comprehensive of the original set?

Comment: Indeed, that is another property, I had forgotten it. But is not the one I was referring to. Look at that: let $S=\{1,2\}$ and $T=\{3,4\}$; their union is the set $X$ in your example and they are disjoint. However, they don't agree with the equivalence classes we had. So, another necessary condition is that any pair of elements in each set $S$ must be related by $R$. With this in mind, consider now $S=\{1\}$ and $T=\{2,3}$. They are disjoint, their union is $X$ and any pair of elements are related by $R$. But they cannot be regarded as the equivalence classes yet. One extra condition is needed

Comment: Summarising the above: you have to impose to the sets $S$ the condition of being an equivalence class. Then, the solution would be something that \texit{The elements of $X/R$ are the maximal elements of $P(X)$ for which any pair of elements is related by $R$} (maximal in the sense that if $t\notin S$, then there is no $s\in S$ such that $sRt$). This statement automatically implies that they are disjoint and that their union is $X$.

Comment: I appreciate your patience and elaboration on this matter. I've tried to digest what you've said and modified the statement again. Hopefully this is more accurate.

Comment: You're welcome. We are here to help (or at least try to).

Comment: I think the current guess is wrong because it doesn't capture the MAXIMAL piece of the puzzle. In the example where ={1,2,3}, a set $S = \{1\}$ would pass the test, as it's a subset of an equivalence class.

Answer (score 2):

You might have missed that the equivalence relation $R$ is *given*. Formally, $R$ is a *given* subset of $X \times X$. The notation $X/R$ has something to do with $R$ itself, so it makes no sense to ignore the given equivalence relation $R$ and think of $X/R$ as something to do with *all* equivalence relations.

Also, you left out something quite important in your first "..." and I'll put it back in (maybe it was left implicit by the author, but for present purposes it's very worthwhile to be as explicit as possible):

> We shall write $X/R$ for the set of all equivalence classes **of the equivalence relation $R$**.

So each element of $X/R$ is a certain equivalence class of the equivalence relation $R$, which is a certain subset of $X$, which is a certain element of $\mathscr P(X)$. Since each element of $X/R$ is an element of $\mathscr P(X)$ it follows that $X/R$ is a subset of $\mathscr P(X)$.

Now, Halmos' exercise is asking for a bit more than that, he's asking you to write the exact mathematical expression that specifies which elements of $\mathscr P(X)$ are in its subset $X/R$, so there's still work to be done.

**Added:** One thing that is clearly missing from your latest specification is quantifiers: the defining condition 
$$(s \in S) \iff ([t \in S] \land [s \space R \space t])
$$
of your set builder notation has no quantifiers on the variables $s$ and $t$, which violates the grammar of set builder notation: there should be *no free variables* except for $S$. There's actually some "quantifier words" in your English translation, e.g. "*there is* also $t$ in $S$", however I don't think you're on the right track there.

Here's a defining condition that could work
$$(S \ne \emptyset) \,\,\text{and}\,\, \bigl(\forall s \in S, \forall t \in X, \space (s \space R \space t) \iff t \in S \bigr)
$$

Comment: I've attempted a different specification based on the feedback you and Dog_69 provided. I tried to build a definition as primitive as I could while still emphasizing that it's drawing on a subset of $\mathscr P(X)$.

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer.

Comment: Nitpick: the _grammar or set builder notation_ allows free variables just fine -- in this example $R$ it self is, and should be, a free variable. The variables $s$ and $t$ _are but should not be_ free variables, but the problem is semantic rather than grammatical.

Comment: Point taken. I'm rather loose with linguistic terms, I must admit.

Comment: Hmm, looks like the defining condition currently at the end of the answer would allow $S$ to be any union of equivalence classes, instead of just a single equivalence class.

Comment: Hah, you're right. Trickier than it looks! I'm fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial thought was wrong. $X/R$ denotes the set of all equivalence classes of the elements of $X$ with respect to the equivalence relation $R$ defined. Then

$$X/R=\{x/R:x\in X\},$$

where $x/R$ denotes the equivalence class of $x$ (I prefere the notation $[x]$):

$$x/R=\{y\in X:(x,y)\in R\}.$$

As you can see, $x/R$ is a subset of $X$ and thus an element of $P(X)$. That means $X/R$ is a collection of elements of $P(X)$. Hence $X/R$ is a subset of $P(X)$.

Noe, why is he worried about this?Well, because, as we have seen, $X/R$ is a set of subsets, so it may be not a set (do you know Russell's paradox?). However, the fact that $X/R\subset P(X)$ ensures that $X/R$ is actually a set. The reasoning is:

$$ X \mbox{set} \Rightarrow $P(X) \mbox{set} $$

and any subset of a set is itself a set.

P.S. I misunderstood Halmos's exercise, the reasoning may be useful though.

Comment: I've attempted a different specification based on the feedback you and Lee Mosher provided. It is not much different, as far as I can tell, from the definition you supplied for $X/R$ except that it uses primitives more. Does it look correct?

Comment: No, I'm afraid $X/R$ is not described in such a way in terms of $P(X)$.

Comment: The first definition of $X/R$ is perfectly fine thanks to the Axiom of Replacement, though. It's just not the one Halmos is fishing for in this exercise.

Comment: @HenningMakholm: What do you mean exactly by "the first definition of $X/R$", the one I wrote or the definition sated in OP's question?

Comment: The first one in this answer.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Ok. Thanks for the remark. Unfortunately, I have never been comfortable with the Axiom of Replacement, I understand the idea but the technical definition, so I prefer to avoid it if possible. In this case it is easy to see that $X/R\subset P(X)$; since $X$ is a set, $P(X)$ is too (Axiom of power set) and then $X/R$ is also a set (Axiom schema of specification?). This reasoning is simpler for me, but thanks for the point.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since the original question went up, so I'll try to give a complete answer here.

As Lee Mosher notes, $R$ is given, not arbitrary, so we can use it in our final condition.

The fact that $R$ is an equivalence relation means that given some $x \in X$, the equivalence class of $x$ is a set of elements $y \in X$ such that $(x, y) \in R$.

As you've described above, we know that

- every equivalence class is a subset of $X$
- $X/R$ is a set of these subsets of $X$, and is therefore itself a subset of $\mathscr P(X)$
- every equivalence class is disjoint; we can't have any overlap in the subsets that we select with our condition.

**I think the only condition that satisfies these constraints is the following:**

$$X/R = \{S \in \mathscr P(X)\setminus\{\varnothing\}: (S \times S) = \{ (a, b) \in R: a \in S \lor b \in S \}$$

In English, this condition selects for subsets $S$ of $\mathscr P(X)$ (without the empty set, which can't be an equivalence class) where every element satisfies the relation $R$ to every other element in that same subset $S$.

The filter on $R$ selects out ordered pairs within the relation $R$ that concern elements that exist within the subset $S$ being considered.

Comment: No, that won't work. If we take $X=\mathbb Z$ and $R$ to be congruence modulo 42, then your definition would say that $\{2,86\}$ is a possible $S$ because indeed $$\{2,86\}×\{2,86\}=\{(a,b)∈R\mid a∈\{2,86\},b∈\{2,86\}\}$$ Instead of the equivalence classes, your definition picks out the equivalence classes _and every subset of every equivalence class_.

Comment: @HenningMakholm what I was trying to create with my condition was a subset of $R$ where any pair with $a \in S$ or $b \in S$ would be included... which, in the example above, would be an entire congruence class modulo 42, right? Which would contain many more elements than $\{2,86\} \times \{2,86\}$, and hence would rule out the subsets of the equivalence classes.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think that maybe you read my "or" as an "and", which indeed would generate a set of the equivalence classes along with every subset of every equivalence class. Is that right? As an aside, I think this latter version, though not very useful, could be generated also via the more concise $\{S \in \mathscr P(X): (S \times S) \subset R \}$.

Comment: Hmm, right. I did misread that. However you're still declaring $\varnothing$ to be an equivalence class ...

Comment: @HenningMakholm good catch again. I've adjusted my answer, which I think is still elegant? Also looks like the other answers saw a few updates so I'll peruse those as well. Thanks and let me know what you think of this adjustment!

Comment: x @Sam, I agree that it seems to work correctly now. Elegance is a subjective matter, so I will not press that, but personally I'd find it clearer to simply have an $\exists$ that says "there is an element whose equivalence class this is".